# Firemonkey TListBox.OnClick - which item is clicked?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistbox

Delphi 10.2.2 mobile

Starting with a blank mobile project, I drop a TListBox on the form. I add two TListBoxItems.

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('ListBoxItem.itemindex = ' + ListBox1.ItemIndex.ToString);
end;
```

When I click on the first item in Windows and Macintosh, the OnClick() correctly reports that item index 0 has been clicked.

When I click on the first item in mobile (iOS and Android) the OnClick() reports the item index as -1 (not 0 as it should). Then it goes on to highlight the first item.

If I then click on the second item in mobile, the OnClick() reports the item index as 0 (not 1 as it should). Then it goes on to highlight the second item.

How can I get the correct item in OnClick() when clicking in a TListBox on mobile?

Comment: This smells like a bug that should be reported to Emba.

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19266

Comment: Notwithstanding the bug: is there a problem with using OnItemClick?

Comment: Just use the OnChange event, it passes the item that was selected/clicked and is called AFTER ItemIndex is updated.

Comment: There is a problem with OnItemClick in that it leaves the item highlighted even after the list has been emptied and replaced with the new selections.

Comment: The OnChange event is triggered when code adds items to the list. This is not helpful if one just needs to have an event when an item is being selected by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly the `OnClick` event is being triggered before the `ItemIndex` is updated. So you will have to delay processing until after the `ItemIndex` has a chance to be updated first.  You can:

- use `TThread.ForceQueue()` (10.2 Tokyo+ only):

  ```
  procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ShowMessage('ListBoxItem.itemindex = ' + ListBox1.ItemIndex.ToString);
      end
    );
  end;
  ```
- use `TThread.Queue()`:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            ShowMessage('ListBoxItem.itemindex = ' + ListBox1.ItemIndex.ToString);
          end
        );
      end
    ).Start;
  end;
  ```
- use a short timer:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    ShowMessage('ListBoxItem.itemindex = ' + ListBox1.ItemIndex.ToString);
  end;
  ```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to peek at the value that is about to be assigned to ItemIndex but the timer method works well enough.